# Angular Material Design datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using angular 1.6, material design 1.1.1, while using the datepicker, exactly like they says in their documentation, I'm getting an empty window while clicking on the datepicker, it shows only the days letter (S S M T W T F ) and only when scrolling inside that window the dates start showing.
Any suggestions? thanks

```
<md-input-container flex>
    <label>Pick a date</label>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" name="dateField" md-min-date="minDate"
            md-max-date="maxDate"></md-datepicker>

    <div ng-messages="myOtherForm.dateField.$error">
            <div ng-message="valid">The entered value is not a date!</div>
            <div ng-message="required">This date is required!</div>
            <div ng-message="mindate">Date is too early!</div>
            <div ng-message="maxdate">Date is too late!</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

The JS:

```
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMdIcons', 'ngMessages']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($timeout , $scope){

  $scope.myDate = new Date();

  $scope.minDate = new Date(
      $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
      $scope.myDate.getMonth() - 2,
      $scope.myDate.getDate());

  $scope.maxDate = new Date(
      $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
      $scope.myDate.getMonth() + 2,
      $scope.myDate.getDate());

  $scope.onlyWeekendsPredicate = function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return day === 0 || day === 6;
  };

});
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet or JS fiddle link

Comment: Hey Nobal, thanks, snippet added to the question

Comment: Thanks. Please add the JS part too

Comment: I'm tired of material datepicker. So i am using https://github.com/alenaksu/mdPickers

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a bug in 1.6.X RC versions. Just use Angular 1.5.9 instead and here is a working sample.

```
var myDate = new Date(2016, 11, 3);

  $scope.minDate = new Date(
      myDate.getFullYear(),
      myDate.getMonth() - 2,
      myDate.getDate());

  $scope.maxDate = new Date(
      myDate.getFullYear(),
      myDate.getMonth() + 2,
      myDate.getDate());

  $scope.onlyWeekendsPredicate = function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return day === 0 || day === 6;
  };
```

http://codepen.io/samithaf/pen/XNzwMP